# ember-routemanager not responding to set('location', '...')

Tags: url-routing, ember.js

I have an application where I'm trying to use [ember-routemanager](https://github.com/ghempton/ember-routemanager). (I'm using `rake-pipeline` as my build environment, but I don't think that's relevant. Or is it?) The problem is, the app seems to be ignoring routes in the location bar.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/3D34B/2/) shows the state manager setting up and entering the entry state properly. After two and a half seconds, the script runs `App.stateManager.set('location', 'desktop');` which according to the ember-routemanager README should move me to the state with "desktop" as its route parameter (right?). But it doesn't.

(This is as close as I can get to cloning the problem in jsfiddle, where I can't easily put a path in the location bar. When I do that on my development environment, e.g. http://localhost:9292/desktop or http://localhost:9292/#desktop , it's clear that the app is not consuming the path; it returns "Entity not found: /desktop".)

Note that [another version of the same fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/3D34B/3/) which uses `goToState` instead of setting `location` works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Code:

```js
Sylvius.stateManager = Ember.RouteManager.create({

    initialState: 'launch',
    enableLogging: true,
    wantsHistory: true,

    launch: Em.ViewState.create({
        view: Sylvius.LaunchView,
    }),
    desktop: Em.ViewState.create({
        view: Sylvius.DesktopView,
        route: 'desktop',

        sectionSelected: Em.State.create({
            route: ':sectionSlug',

            enter: function(manager, transition) {
                console.log('We found the slug: ' + Sylvius.stateManager.getPath('params.sectionSlug'));
            }
        })

    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining a route like `/desktop/:sectionSlug` for your `sectionSelected` state. If you invoke `Sylvius.stateManager.set('location', 'desktop/123');` then it works as expected.

If you want a state which handles the route '/desktop' you have to create a new state without a `route` property, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/NMgKH/:

```js
index: Em.State.create({
    enter: function(manager, transition){
        this._super();
        console.log('invoked for /desktop');
    }
})
```

Comment: Exactly. rlivesy pointed this out to me in IRC, but he didn't have time to post it here.